# Can you get file path from StreamReader object?

Tags: c#, path, streamreader

Is it possible to get the path that was used in the StreamReader constructor from the StreamReader object?

```
        using (StreamReader fileStream = new StreamReader(filePath))
        {
            string path = fileStream.???
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`StreamReader` exposes the stream from which it's reading via the `BaseStream` property.  If the reader's stream is a `FileStream`, you can use its `Name` property to get the path of the file.

```
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(filePath))
{
    string path = (reader.BaseStream as FileStream)?.Name;
}
```

*Note: I renamed the variable to prevent possible confusion, since it IS a reader that HAS a stream.*

In this contrived example, it's obvious that it's a `FileStream` but the type test is necessary if you have a method that's taking a `StreamReader`.

That said, you're causing the abstraction to leak by doing this.  If you need to know the file name, you should explicitly require the file name or a `FileStream` instance.